# SQL , How to count deposit success rate?

Tags: mysql, sql

Overall, for each customer, how many deposit attempts were made on each payment method and what is the deposit success rate?
I have 3 tables

Task_1

| mk_Calendar | mk_Customer | mk_PaymentMethod | mk_paymentstatus | amount_EUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 13.80163332 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 27.421812 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 95.2215573 |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 73.35898505 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod

| mk_PaymentMethod | PaymentMethodName | PaymentType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Method A | Type A |
| 2 | Method B | Type A |
| 3 | Method C | Type B |

DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus

| mk_paymentstatus | StatusName | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending | payment is pending approval |
| 2 | Completed | payment has been completed successfully |
| 3 | Failed | payment has failed |

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    Task_1.mk_Customer, DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodName, 
    COUNT(DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus.StatusName.Completed) / COUNT(DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus.StatusName) AS rate  
FROM 
    Task_1
INNER JOIN    
    DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod ON Task_1.mk_PaymentMethod = DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod.mk_PaymentMethod
INNER JOIN 
    DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus ON Task_1.mk_paymentstatus = DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus.mk_paymentstatus
GROUP BY 
    Task_1.mk_Customer, DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod.PaymentMethodName
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However we ask members to write comprehensive questions, not relying on external resources. Feel free to have a look at the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: What's the expected result for the given sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from counting the number of rows with a status `Completed`.

You were quite close, using a `CASE` statement would solve this particular problem. Is the following query correct or is there another problem?

```
SELECT
  task.mk_Customer,
  method.PaymentMethodName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status.StatusName = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  /
  COUNT(status.StatusName)
  AS rate
FROM Task_1 task
INNER JOIN DBtest_dim_PaymentMethod method ON task.mk_PaymentMethod = method.mk_PaymentMethod
INNER JOIN DBtest_dim_PaymentStatus status ON task.mk_paymentstatus = status.mk_paymentstatus
GROUP BY task.mk_Customer, method.PaymentMethodName
```

I used aliases to make your query a bit more compact without hopefully losing meaningfulness.

Another solution would be to use `AVG` instead of `SUM` and `COUNT`.

```
SELECT
  -- (...)
  AVG(CASE WHEN status.StatusName = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rate
-- (...)
```